# Is usage of white colored paper so widespread due to economic factors?

Tags: price, aggregate-production

Why is white paper so popular? Is it so because it's cheaper or because it's a widely accepted standard for color?

Comment: Not sure if I hit the right server with this question as it's only economy related...

Comment: Actually this is an interesting economic example.  The main use of white paper is for writing and printing.  So white paper and black (or other dark colour) ink are complementary goods.  Equally, though less often used, black paper and white ink are complementary goods.  So the question is then why the former _combination_ of goods is more popular.